# Помогите найти минимальное значение цены каждого товара и вывести его на экран

Tags: java, коллекции

Если три класса. Первый класс Good

```
class Good {
    String name;
    double price;

    public Good(String name, double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price=price;
    }
}
```

Второй класс OnlineStore

```
class OnlineStore {
    String name;
    List<Good> goods;
    public OnlineStore(String name, List<Good> list) {
            this.name = name;
            this.goods = list;
    }

}
```

Третий класс ProductSearchSrvice

```
class ProductSearchSrvice {
    List<OnlineStore> store;

    public ProductSearchSrvice(List<OnlineStore> store) {
        if (store.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

И есть класс, где все происходит

```
public class Lab10 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Good Tuner = new Good("Tuner",350.0);
        Good Cable_HDMI = new Good("Cable HDMI",29.60);
        Good Control_panel = new Good("Control panel",150.50);
        Good Tuner_1 = new Good("Tuner",1323.0);
        Good Cable_HDMI_1 = new Good("Cable_HDMI",470.0);
        Good Control_panel_1 = new Good("Control_panel",617.0);
        Good Tuner_2 = new Good("Tuner",567.89);
        Good Cable_HDMI_2 = new Good("Cable_HDMI",249.50);
        Good Control_panel_2 = new Good("Control_panel",850.0);

        List<Good> listOfMirElectroniki = new ArrayList<Good>();
        List<Good> listOfHIKVISION = new ArrayList<Good>();
        List<Good> listOfOLX = new ArrayList<Good>();

        listOfMirElectroniki.add(Tuner);
        listOfMirElectroniki.add(Cable_HDMI);
        listOfMirElectroniki.add(Control_panel);

        listOfHIKVISION.add(Tuner_1);
        listOfHIKVISION.add(Cable_HDMI_1);
        listOfHIKVISION.add(Control_panel_1);

        listOfOLX.add(Tuner_2);
        listOfOLX.add(Cable_HDMI_2);
        listOfOLX.add(Control_panel_2);

        OnlineStore MirElectroniki = new OnlineStore("Mir Electroniki", listOfMirElectroniki);
        OnlineStore HIKVISION = new OnlineStore("HIKVISION", listOfHIKVISION);
        OnlineStore OLX = new OnlineStore("OLX", listOfOLX);

    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Я не понимаю, как это сделать. Задание не сложное, но я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: Тут каждый товар по 1 экземпляру. Среди чего искать? Или программа должна интуитивно понять, что например Tuner_1 и Tuner_2 - это товары одной категории и сравнивать Их цены?

Comment: А как сделать их одной категории?

Comment: Можно в `Good` добавить поле `category`. Если задание на полиморфизм/наследование, то надо от класса `Good` унаследовать 3 класса и определять потом по `instanceof`...